# Django: TypeError at / context must be a dict rather than tuple

Tags: django, django-views

I keep getting an error message when executing this views settings:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def home_screen_view(request):
    print(request.headers)
    return render(request, 'base.html', ())
```

so I need your help

Answer (score 0):

Try following the information the error message displays... Try replacing () with {}

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, the context should be a *dictionary*, not a tuple. For an empty dictionary, you use curly brackets (`{}`), not parenthesis (`()`):

from django.shortcuts import render

```
def home_screen_view(request):
    print(request.headers)
    return render(request, 'base.html', {})
    #                  {} instead of () ^^
```